# ASP NET image onmouseover not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 images in my page. What i want to do is, when i move the mouse over 2nd image, the first image will change to other image, but something is not working.

Code:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgProduct" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/1.png" />
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/2.png"  onmouseover="imgProduct.src='Images/2.png';"/>
```

If i change the ID in `onmouseover="imgProduct.src=` to any image id in masterpage, that image is changing correctly, but its not working in the default page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Page_Load event add this line.

```
Image2.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",imgProduct.ClientID+".src='Images/2.png'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/2.png"  
onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('imgProduct').src=this.src;" />
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply.
Its still the same - working with images in masterpage, but not in the default page.