# Call C# function from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning,

I have the following asp Image and would like to add the on mouse over event, as follow:

```
<asp:Image ID="MapImage" runat="server" Height="601px" Width="469px" OnMouseOver="OnMouseOverMap"/>
```

I have also added the following method on the C# code:

```
protected void OnMouseOverMap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 9;
    }
```

I also have created the same method without the parameters but I cannot manage to call that C# function.

Can somebody help me with this issue?, How can I do to call the C# function from the ASP code.

Cheers!

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the difference between server-side code and client-side code. You can't directly invoke a C# method from an `onmouseover` event.

Comment: As @JLRishe says, for the code to fire you'd need the page to postback on Mouse Over, which would be a bit weird... You can use Ajax to call server side code from a client event, would that help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a code-behind method from aspx page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754016/how-to-call-a-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page)

Comment: Yes, I dont have any problem in using Ajax, but I do not know how that works. I am a database developer trying to learn asp.net and c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no OnMouseOver server-side event on asp:Image object.

What you can do you can write js function called on client-side onmouseover event and inside that function trigger click on hidden button or you can change Image to ImageButton and trigger click on that image.

```
    <asp:Image ID="MapImage" runat="server" Height="601px" Width="469px" onmouseover="javascript:foo()"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" OnClick="OnMouseOverMap" />
```

And in js function:

```
    function foo()
{
document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

Comment: Note that this will typically trigger a postback and cause your whole page to reload. If that's what you want to do, fine, but that sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: @JLRishe Then He can wrap this code with `Update Panels` or Ajax Calls with jqurey

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Sure he can, but using Ajax calls with jQuery would have nothing to do with the solution proposed above.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you are supposed to insert javascript code there and not a "code behind event handler reference". See [ASP NET image onmouseover not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768064/asp-net-image-onmouseover-not-working) for example.